# Is there any way of providing Audio answer as stream with ChatGPT in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to get answer from `ChatGPT` and provide answer as audio in `Flutter`.

When I look through document of ChatGPT API, I found `text to speech`.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-to-speech

But this speaks input itself, not answer from question.

So Now what I do is I get answer from ChatGPT and then, after getting all answer, I read that answer strings from package `flutter_tts` (text to speech).

But the limit of this process is user should wait for answer to finished before AI speaks answer too long.

When I use ChatGPT 3.5 from app, It provides audio question and audio answer as stream. So audio answer comes so quickly after use asks.

And there's so many apps to provide ChatGPT answer with audio.

Is this function not provided in API Now? If so, How do they provide this function? please let me know.